# Populate Woocommerce Cart using session data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking to have a one page order form for a list of products, wherein customers can increase and decrease the desired amounts of each products (One page website, using the loop or product archive page) before proceeding to the next step.

I need a button at the bottom of the website that will populate the cart with the quantities stored in a session before moving onto the checkout.

I've tried various plugins. Most incorporate this for single product pages, but none seem to offer the same capability for the archive/loop page. I've tried to build my own using javascript increment boxes but had no success. One "+" button changed every value on the page.

I'm new to woocommerce but experienced with php.

I hope I have explained this clearly enough, if not please ask for me to confirm because this problem needs to be solved soon.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you are searching for. the cart page looks like what you want, with possibility to change the amount of product in the cart

Comment: That's exactly what I want, but with one button that adds all the products at once! Thank you for your response

Comment: have you try to make a grouped product ? http://docs.woothemes.com/document/chained-products-vs-product-bundles-vs-force-sells-vs-grouped-products/

Comment: Grouping would remove the main feature of the site :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my problem by using WooCommerce with an Add All **checked items** to cart.